# GDAL Slope function not working with SRTM DEM data?

Tags: dem, slope, srtm

I'm a QGIS rookie trying to generate slope data for research projects in South Africa.

I've managed to download DEM data from Bing Aerial maps using the SRTM-downloader but cant get the GDAL slope function output in QGIS to work as seen in other successful efforts online. The map generated looks like the attached pic.The slope value ranges between 0 (black) and 89.99 (white).[image]

The aspect function seems to work but can't crack the slope function, any suggestions?

Comment: Transform your SRTM data to any fitting UTM zone, then it should work.

Comment: For slope to work, the X/Y units must be the same as the Z units.